# “I/O Error Occurred” in vSphere Client 4.1 uploading to datastore

Tags: vmware-vsphere, vmware-vcenter, datastore, vsphere-client

Environment is VMware 4.1, 2 ESXi servers with a iSCSI 6TB datastore with 1.5TB free.  ~30 VMs, small load, VMs working well.

On the datastore I have an ISOs folder.  Typically, I can upload new ISOs there that VMs can mount.  Today I have a problem uploading a new ISO. The "Uploading..." dialog pops up, hangs for a while, and then the "I/O Error Occurred" displays. I have tried this with 2 ISOs, one 4GB and another 600MB.  The ISOs are on the desktop of a standalone 2008 R2 server that I use for a few things, including Veeam backups and vCenter server.

I then tried the opposite, downloading a small floppy image from the same folder, to my desktop.  It drew the file on the desktop in preparation of downloading, but then errored out with the same "I/o error occurred".

I logged out of vCenter client, back in - still failed.  I logged out of my personal login to vCenter and back in as administrator, still failed.  I rebooted the server and logged in as administrator, still failed.

Search pulled up a thread with similar behavior.  I checked, my HP DL360G5 with Broadcom GigE NICs are set to Auto.  ["I/O Error Occurred" in vSphere Client working with ESXi](https://serverfault.com/questions/76095/i-o-error-occurred-in-vsphere-client-working-with-esxi)
I changed the Broadcom NIC's setting from Auto to Gbps, relogged into vCenter client - and no change.

Anyone have any advice?

Followup: I was able to delete a large unneeded ISO freeing up an additional 7GB.  I re-attempted uploading the 600MB ISO with the same lack of success - I/O error occurred.

Comment: 4.1? *taps watch* it *is* 2015 right?

Comment: ha!  It's a US based manufacturer.  How many of those are there left in 2015?  The DL360 G6 is considered new server equipment here.  :)  Sometimes you got to work with what you have got - and it does the trick.  While I found your reply very funny, do you have anything helpful to add?

Comment: not really, I used 4.1 at the time and copying files into and out of datastore *remains* an issue even with 5.5 but it's usually one that rebooting your vCenter can fix - I'd try that, or adding a new temporary datastore to see if it's that datastore or any datastore that's the problem. Also try attaching to the host directly copying that way - that's all I can think of right now sorry.

Comment: Chopper, you really helped.  I was able to connect directly to the host from vCenter and make the proper transfers.  With that working, I made a conclusion that vCenter was broken in some way - and reinstalled it.  It is properly working.  Thanks for the idea that led to the solution.

Comment: Glad you're happy now

Comment: 6TB of Datastore? That is 3x the maximum of what is allowed to Vmware/vmfs3 version